# navigation menu directive refresh on user login or logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu directive containing user info (login, logout...) witch changes state as a user logs in or out.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn"><a href="#/login">Sign in</a></li>
    <li ng-show="isLoggedIn"><a href="#/profile">{{ currentUser.name }}</a></li>
    <li ng-show="isLoggedIn" ng-click="logout()"><a>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to structure my index.html like this

```
<navigation></navigation>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

This doesn't work as wanted because I redirect on login/logout : only ng-view gets refreshed but not the navigation directive...

To work around this I have instead, put the navigation directive in the begining of each of my page templates that are loaded in ng-view.

Is this the best way to proceed ? I've seen it done elsewere but I find it inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this can set the isLoggedIn variable in $rootScope
and update it to 1 and 0 whenever you log in or logout